# Why Dns.Resolve in my C# app takes x3 on W2008R2?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I have C# code which takes x3 longer to execute on W2008R2 vs W7

the code is very simple (getting host name):

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        IPHostEntry ip = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
        string s = ip.HostName;

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
```

I did stop some services on W2008. May be I accidentally stopped something which helps to propagate DNS notifications or whatever...

Any thoughts?

**EDIT: I am sorry I havent told. The x3 means: on W7 it takes <1ms and on W2008 it is either 2 or 9ms... It is not really about timing out.**

Comment: Do the two machines have the same DNS settings?  Is the Win2008 box running a DNS server?

Comment: Are you trying to resolve the same host name? Are you flushing the DNS cache on both of your test systems before running your test?

Comment: No DNS server on either of them. Settings - DNS provided by ISP (two different providers as the computers in different places).

Comment: @Joe - how do I flush DNS cache?

Comment: On a Windows machine: from a command prompt type: ipconfig/flushdns

Comment: ipconfig/flushdns says: Could not flush the DNS .. Function failed during execution. What it could be?

Comment: @Bobb, then there's definitely something wrong with your network configuration...

Comment: @All: I don't think this belongs on SO; the code is perfectly fine, something must be wrong with the server's networking.

Comment: yes. but I thought SO is StackOverflow with software questions. This is ServerFault where the DNS settings / networking questions are appropriate? Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you try resolving that name (or any other name) *outside* of your program, f.e. using `ping` or `nslookup`?

The application should run exactly the same on both computers regardless of the O.S., so this might very well be a DNS problem. If the machine's name is not registered in the DNS server(s) the machine is using, or if the machine can't reach at all its configured DNS server(s), or if the server(s) can't resolve the name, or (*many other possible issues here*), the query will fail and/or timeout, and only *then* it will be resolved using the local `hosts` file.

You should definitely check your DNS configuration.

Comment: I thought the hosts file was checked before doing a DNS lookup?

Comment: Actually it should, but if you open it in Windows 7/200R2, you'll see a comment saying "local host name resolution is handled within DNS now"...

Comment: guys sorry. You lost me here. The host name is the name of the computer running that program. So it is name like MYSUPERDUPERPC - the one I set in System -> Computer name. The both computers are far apart - W7 is at home in the UK and W2008 in US. Both machines uses some other DNS from ISP. No local DNS on them. Tell me - is it going to lookup through DNS servers to find out the name of the local host??

Comment: ok. I just tried ping MYSUPERDUPERPC and it works similar on both machines. it shows <1ms ping and no delays.

Comment: flushdns doesnt work. perhaps I stopped necessary service....